# Why doesn't fontspec LetterSpace and WordSpace apply to ':' and '/' in a url?

Tags: hyperref, fontspec, typewriter, letterspacing

I'd like to widen the space between each character in mono-spaced contexts (e.g. `\url{}` and coding example blocks). I figured fontspec's LetterSpace and WordSpace options would be the simplest way to do this, so I tried the following:

```
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=0.8, LetterSpace=150, WordSpace=150]
```

*(I'm using a value of 150 here to make the issue more obvious)*

This seems to work okay for `{\tt http://example.com}`, but `\url{}` gives funky results:

[image: example of a poorly-spaced URL]

What's going on here? Are LetterSpace and WordSpace not the appropriate tools for the job? Is there a better approach or something else I need to set?

I'm using MacTeX 2016 and `lualatex`, if that's relevant.

As requested, here's a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=0.8, LetterSpace=150, WordSpace=150]

\begin{document}

\url{http://apple.com/}

{\tt http://apple.com/}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. If possible, use a font available in standard TeX distributions. If the problem cannot be reproduced except with Menlo, then please provide a link, if possible, to a suitable source.

Comment: Just by way of general advice, if you're using lualatex, you should replace `{\tt foo}`, etc. with `\texttt{foo}` (or `{\ttfamily foo}` if you really want), `{\tt foo}`, `{\it foo}`, etc. are 20+ years deprecated.

Comment: @cfr I see the same behaviour with Latin Modern Mono, so this doesn't seem to be Menlo-specific.

Comment: Not just if you are using LuaLaTeX - if you are using LaTeX at all.

Comment: So better to use `Latin Modern Mono` in your example since almost everyone will have that.

Comment: @cfr true :) I meant to highlight that these are deprecated with lualatex, but not luatex, but I could have added that as an aside. splicer I get the same with Liberation Mono (nice font actually, quite glad I had to look for a substitute to Menlo now, but cfr's right, the more generic and applicable to everyone you can make your MWE, the better it will be for them, and the quicker your answers can come)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL is typeset in maths mode with maths spacing. Forward slashes and full-stops are typeset as binary operators ('mathbin'), colons are typeset as relations ('mathrel'). The former are classified as 'Break' characters; the latter as 'BigBreak' characters. This is, of course, used to control which characters may be followed by a line break.

Hence, to change the spacing around these characters, you must change the configuration of maths mode spacing which is active when the URL is typeset. To do this, the `url` package provides a `\Urlmuskip` dimension which can be modified at will.

For example,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=0.8, LetterSpace=150, WordSpace=150]
\urlstyle{tt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\Urlmuskip = 22mu plus 10mu
\begin{document}

\nolinkurl{http://apple.com/}

\url{http://apple.com/}

\ttfamily{http://apple.com/}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: modified spacing for URLs]

Comment: "The URL is typeset in maths mode with maths spacing." That's really interesting, I never knew that, do you know why that's done?

Comment: No. I thought it was interesting, too. I only found it out answering this question. Try `texdoc url`. If I missed something or you figure something out, please let me know.

Comment: @Au101 That is, it says that it allows `context-sensitive linebreaking` but I'm not really sure why that requires maths mode. I can see how it is used in terms of making different characters different kinds of maths atoms. But I'm not sure why it needed to be done that way.

Comment: @cfr in inline math line breaking doesn't depend on hyphenation patterns but on \binoppenalty and \relpenalty which are break points.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Is that really the only or easiest way? Easier than changing the hyphenation patterns as you would for a different language, for example? Or is it because you need to line break without getting hyphens?

Comment: Imho it would be much more difficult with hyphenation patterns. E.g. you would need quite a lot patterns, to allow for more or less restricted breaks in urls.