# Is it possible to use LetterSpace (fontspec) with urls (hyperref)?

Tags: fonts, xetex, hyperref, fontspec

Using fontspec (with `xelatex` in this case), `LetterSpace` in an option for fonts that allows for adjustment of the spacing between glyphs.

However, the `hyperref` package seems to override this, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase,LetterSpace=-10]{Liberation Mono}
\newfontfamily\regularmono[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Liberation Mono}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

http://www.example.com                 % main font

\texttt{http://www.example.com}        % uses monofont
                                       % respects LetterSpace

{\regularmono http://www.example.com}  % without LetterSpace

\url{http://www.example.com}           % uses monofont
                                       % does not respect LetterSpace

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: four lines of "http://www.example.com" showing the varying behaviour of the different formatting commands above]

In this example, the monospace text with `\texttt{}` uses the `LetterSpace` setting, whereas the monospace text with `\url{}`, while clearly using the same font, does not appear to respect the `LetterSpace` setting, despite it being set for all occurrences of the font (or so I thought I understood).

My question is what options there are for getting past this apparent limitation.  In other words, how can one adjust the spacing between glyphs in `hyperref` urls?

Edit: [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326809/why-doesnt-fontspec-letterspace-and-wordspace-apply-to-and-in-a-url/) was asked before (I looked several times for related questions but somehow missed this one).

Comment: A workaround: `\href{http://www.example.com}{\texttt{http://www.example.com}}` (_does not handle special characters in the url_).

Comment: This is the best answer so far.  If you'd type it up and add a line to my MWE with this solution and show the output, I'd be happy to accept it.  If you'd prefer not to, I can write it up as an answer and accept it.

Also, which "special symbols" aren't handled?  Punctuation characters seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround: `\href{http://www.example.com}{\texttt{http://www.example.com}}`

But you can't use special characters (as `~`, `%` or `#`...) directly in the URL printed by `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase,LetterSpace=-10]{Liberation Mono}
\newfontfamily\regularmono[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Liberation Mono}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

http://www.example.com                 % main font

\texttt{http://www.example.com}        % uses monofont
                                       % respects LetterSpace

{\regularmono http://www.example.com}  % without LetterSpace

\url{http://www.example.com}           % uses monofont
                                       % does not respect LetterSpace

\href{http://www.example.com}{\texttt{http://www.example.com}}
                                       % uses monofont
                                       % does respect LetterSpace

\href{http://www.example.com/%special#characters~}{\texttt{http://www.example.com/\%special\#characters\~{}}}

\url{http://www.example.com/%special#characters~}

\end{document}
```

When compiled with `lualatex`:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

urls are typeset in math mode and math mode handles spacing differently. With `xelatex` imho your only option it to typeset the url in text mode as suggested by Paul in a comment. With `lualatex` which implements letter spacing differently your example works:

[image]

Comment: The spacing around the punctuation characters in your `lualatex` example seem to behave differently in `\texttt{}` and `\url{}`.  Specifically, the punctuation characters in `\url{}` seem to not respect `LetterSpace`.

Comment: You need to change \Urlmuskip for this spaces. See e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326809/why-doesnt-fontspec-letterspace-and-wordspace-apply-to-and-in-a-url/

Comment: Interesting.  What is the correspondence between `\Urlmuskip` values and `LetterSpace` values?  That is, if I have one set to a given value, how can I calculate what to set the other one to?